# Find area of equilateral $\Delta ABC $

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I'm going to solve this geometry problem without using rotational , any other way like coordinates :

Problem :

Given an equilateral triangle $\Delta ABC $ such that :

$P$ point inside triangle with distance from the vertices of triangle as following in picture :

[image]

How I use coordinates here ?

Can you assist!

---

Thanks!

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3735980)

Answer (score 2):

Orient the triangle to be centered at $(0,0)$ and let $t$ be $\frac{s}{2\sqrt{3}}$ so that
$$A=(2t,0), B=(-t,t\sqrt{3}), C=(-t,-t\sqrt{3}).$$
We have some point $P=(x,y)$ so that
$$(2t-x)^2+y^2=100,\ (t+x)^2+(y-t\sqrt{3})^2=64,\ (t+x)^2+(y+t\sqrt{3})^2=36.$$
I won't do out the algebra here because it's rather messy, but here's the general strategy:

1. Subtract the second and third equations to solve for $y$ in terms of $t$.
2. Subtract the first and second equations to solve for $x$ in terms of $t$ (once you know $y$).
3. Plug this pair $(x,y)$ into one of the three equations, giving a quadratic in $t^2$ (I think). Solve, discard unreasonable solutions, and you're done.

Comment: Can you give the solution of the last system?

Comment: Are [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282t-x%29%5E2%2By%5E2%3D100%2C+%28t%2Bx%29%5E2%2B%28y-t%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%29%5E2%3D64%2C+%28t%2Bx%29%5E2%2B%28y%2Bt%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%29%5E2%3D36) solutions OK or you want step-by-step?

Comment: I need step by step sir if you can ?

Comment: It appears I can but the question is _why_ do I want to spent an hour to fullfill a clear solution way? I don't. And no "sir" please unless you insist. Thanks. @EllenEllen

Answer (score 0):

It's rather a *comment* to the Carl Schildkraut's answer, it's not in a way an answer itself. I already mentioned a link in the comments to the question for which this could be a duplicate, except this question conversely wants coordinates. Vectors are more neat here, IMHO.
Following the steps in the answer we have
0. Expand the things
$$\begin{cases}
4 t^2 - 4 t x + x^2 + y^2 = 100\\
4 t^2 + 2 t x - 2 \sqrt{3} t y + x^2 + y^2 = 64\\
4 t^2 + 2 t x + 2 \sqrt{3} t y + x^2 + y^2 = 36
\end{cases}$$
1.
$$\begin{cases}
4 t^2 - 4 t x + x^2 + y^2 = 100\\
4 t^2 + 2 t x - 2 \sqrt{3} t y + x^2 + y^2 = 64\\
4 \sqrt{3} t y = 36-64
\end{cases}$$
2.
$$\begin{cases}
4 t^2 - 4 t x + x^2 + y^2 = 100\\
6 t x - 2 \sqrt{3} t y = 64-100\\
2 \sqrt{3} t y = -14
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
4 t^2 - 4 t x + x^2 + y^2 = 100\\
6 t x = 64-100-14=-50\\
2 \sqrt{3} t y = -14
\end{cases}$$
3.
$$\begin{cases}
4 t^4 - 4 t^2 ( t x ) + t^2 x^2 + t^2 y^2 = 100t^2\\
4 t x =-\frac{100}{3}\\
2 \sqrt{3} t y = -14
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
12 t^4 - 3 t^2\cdot (4 t x ) + 3 t^2 x^2 + 3 t^2 y^2 = 300t^2\\
4 t x =-\frac{100}{3}\\
\sqrt{3} t y = -7
\end{cases}$$
$$12t^4-200t^2+\frac{625}{3}+49=0$$
$$36t^4-600t^2+772=0$$
$$9t^4-150t^2+193=0$$
$$\frac{D}{4}=75^2-9\cdot 193=36^2\cdot 3$$
$$t^2=\frac{75\pm 36\sqrt{3}}{9}$$
$$t=\pm_2\sqrt{\frac{25}{3}\pm_1 4\sqrt{3}}$$
Any questions welcome.

Comment: Sum the 3 equation to get $x^2+y^2$ as function of $t$. Sum the second and third to get  the value of $tx$ - use the first calculation. Calculate for $t$